# set marker to users location android-google-maps-api

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map application that follows the user and what I want to know is how to add a marker that follows the user. how close is it to just adding a marker at a set place? Can I switch the overlay to track somehow?

Thanks

Comment: You have to remove the overlayItem and place it again at the new location.

Comment: @weakwire, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: you want to place a marker that follows the user. Your problem is getting the location from the user while moving?or move a layout item (marker) to the new location?

Comment: @weakwire, I can get the location from the user while moving. I do want to know how to move the layout item to the new location.

Comment: remove the overlay item or the whole overlay. and then replace it.

Comment: @weakwire, how would I replace the overlay item?

Comment: mapView.getOverlays.clear() to remove the old overlay. And then place it again the way you placed the first overlay with the position you want. Place the overlay and the overlay item.

Comment: @weakwire, Can you put your answer under "answers" so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapView.getOverlays.clear()` to remove the old overlay. And then place it again the way you placed the first overlay with the position you want. Place the overlay and the overlay item.